# Does this "triangular" figure have a name?

Tags: geometry, terminology, circles

Angle subtended at the center by an arc and another angle subtended at the circumference by the same arc: does the resulting figure ($\text{VCOD}$) have a name? The shape is usually shown in most high-school level textbooks, albeit always without specifiying *what it's called.*

[image]

Comment: That looks like a "proof without words" of the [inscribed angle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Statement) $\,\theta= 2 \psi\,$, but I don't know that the figure has any special name or designation.

Comment: I've heard it called the Star Trek Logo.

Comment: Isn't it okay to just call it a concave quadrilateral?

Comment: I guess the fact that the fourth corner is the center of the circle though the other three makes this a specific type of concave quadrilateral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This figure is a **concave kite**, sometimes referred to as a *"**dart**"* or an "***arrowhead***".

> A kite — a quadrilateral whose four sides can be grouped into two pairs of equal-length sides that are adjacent to each other — may be either convex or concave, but the word "kite" is often restricted to the convex variety. A concave kite is sometimes called a "dart" or "arrowhead", and is a type of [pseudotriangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudotriangle).
>
> > Modified excerpt from [Kite (geometry), Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kite_(geometry))

Comment: i dont think VCOD is a kite because VC and VD have different side lengths.